# Creating coefficient matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have 3 elements, $\{A1,A2,A3\}$. I have 3 independent polynomials, stored in a list $\{A1-s*A2,A2,A2+A3\}$. I want to create a matrix form which will help to visualize easily which elements are there.

The matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&1&1 \end{pmatrix}$ implies the first row is the first element of the list and contains both $A1$ and $A2$. The second row implies $A2$ is there only and so on. I have no idea how to implement this in mathematica.

Comment: (1) People here generally like users to post code as copyable *Mathematica* code as well as images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful. (2) have you seen `CoefficientArrays[]`?

Comment: CoefficientArrays[] gives the coefficients. But I want, if they exist, 1 else 0

Comment: In they are numeric coefficients, apply `Unitize[]`.

Comment: no they can be non numeric

Comment: Then use ReplaceAll to replace the nonzero entries

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there with CoefficiantArrays:

```
amat = {a1 - 5 a2, a2, a2 + a3};
Sign[Abs[(CoefficientArrays[amat] // Normal)[[2]]]]

{{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}
```

If you want to have constants that are not expressed as numerical values, then you'll need to inform Mathematica which are to be treated as variables and which as constants. For instance, here we've added two "constants" s and t and built the matrix for "variables" a1, a2, and a3.

```
exp = {a1 - s a2, t a2, a2 + a3};
vars = {a1, a2, a3};
const = {s, t};
Abs[((CoefficientArrays[exp, vars] // Normal)[[2]]) /.Thread[const -> 1]]

{{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}
```

Comment: yes. But I was looking for a code with if statement, since these can be non numeric coefficients

Comment: This does work with arbitrary symbols like a1-a2. No need for If...

Comment: if I have a1-s*a2 where s is a number, how to deal with this? it is giving 4*4 this time

Comment: See update to remove effect of constant multiple

Comment: @TanmoyPati Giving an "MWE" (a minimal working example)  in **code** that illustrates the issues would make it easier for others. Of course, if you would rather make them do that trivial bit of work for you, then you may end up with approximate answers and a lot of back-and-forth....

Comment: `Normal[Unitize[Rest@CoefficientArrays[amat, {a1, a2, a3}]]]` also works